# cron does not execute shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I have created a simple shell script which should be executed via cron but cron does not run it.
I did a google search and found different approaches, which unfortunately don't work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

pwd > output.txt
```

Howerver, when i run the script in terminal it works fine

```
git@ubuntu-20:~/test$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  2 git git 4096 Jan 20 16:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 git git 4096 Jan 20 16:04 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git    0 Jan 20 16:05 file.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 git git   30 Jan 20 15:28 testcron.sh*
git@ubuntu-20:~/test$ cat testcron.sh 
#!/bin/bash

pwd > output.txt
git@ubuntu-20:~/test$ sh testcron.sh 
git@ubuntu-20:~/test$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  2 git git 4096 Jan 20 16:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 git git 4096 Jan 20 16:04 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git    0 Jan 20 16:05 file.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 git git   15 Jan 20 16:05 output.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 git git   30 Jan 20 15:28 testcron.sh*
git@ubuntu-20:~/test$
```

This is the content of *crontab -e*

```
*/1 * * * * touch /home/git/test/file.txt
*/1 * * * * /home/git/test/testcron.sh
```

As you can see, cron runs the first job, so that *file.txt* will be created. Does anyone have an idea why cron doesn't execute the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

The PWD for cron scripts is `/`, and testcron.sh is attempting to write the output.txt file in the PWD. The git user won't have permission to write files in `/`

Solution:

1. the testcron.sh script should `cd` to some directory where you have write privileges, or
2. specify the full path where output.txt should be written